# Best practice for reusing a required npm in each separate module file

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am refactoring my code to keep things way easier into separate modules that are included via module.exports.

Many of these modules use the same required npm. Is it best practice to require the same npm in each separate module or best to include the module only on the main js file and then just make it available for export?

Want to make sure I am following the best practice for any other developers that might get on my codebase later on.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Don't do it. Each module should require it's own. Do not share.

Answer (score 3):

You can safely require the same module many times and it will be still loaded by Node only once. It is cached on the first `require()` and all subsequent requires get the exact same object - which you can even use to pass data around which demonstrates that it must be the same copy of the object even for multiple requires.

For example if you require lodash in one module and add a function to it, it will be available in every other place where lodash is required in the same process, even in different files.

Some people recommend requiring every module only once and sharing to avoid loading it many times but Node doesn't load it many times anyway.

Some people recommend requiring it every time you use it so that every place has it's own fresh copy but this is also not the case as everything gets the same copy anyway.

There are many misconceptions with how require works in Node.

### Example

See this project with two modules, `mod1` and `mod2` that each require `lodash` and export their versions, and an app that requires both of them, changes `lodash.xxx` in one and inspects `lodash.xxx` in the other:

#### `mod1.js`:

```
const lodash = require('lodash');
exports.lodash = lodash;
```

#### `mod2.js`:

```
const lodash = require('lodash');
exports.lodash = lodash;
```

#### `app.js`:

```
const mod1 = require('./mod1');
const mod2 = require('./mod2');
mod1.lodash.xxx = 'XXX';
console.log(mod2.lodash.xxx);
```

Comment: Ok cool, so it should be fine to just include the same library on different modules.

Comment: @jremi Yeah, totally cool. Unless it makes sense to require it once for other reasons. But you can require things like lodash in every file in your project and it's totally fine. It will still get loaded only once and at least you can look at `const _ = require('lodash');` at the top of each file and know what is it.

Comment: I did not test the example... but to make sure I am fully understanding... can you please paste the result of the console.log(mod2.lodash.xxx); I am assuming it will also be resulting in 'XXX' ... is that correct?